# Factorial program in pycharm

Tags: python

```
n= int(input("Enter the number:"))
fact =1
for i in range(1, n+1)
fact = fact*1


print("factorial of the given number is :", fact)
```

I have done this in pycharm, for any number input, the answer is showing as  1.
What is the error here.
Can anybody please help me out
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're missing a colon at the end of the for loop

Comment: yeah, i forget to type in here.
Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing `fact`.

After the first iteration: fact = 1*1, and it stays like that for the second, third and so on.

You might want to do something like:
`fact = fact*i`

Comment: oh , k
I appreciate youThanks for the quick response.